# How to get the list of object properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wonder is there any way that i can get the list of property of an object array? Say i have a code as following :

> var obj = {
> name: 'My Name',
> obj1: {
> age: 18,
> name: "Samuel"
> }
> };

I want an array to display the properties so it will be like this :

> let arr = [age,name];

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get array of keys in an object.